# How can I disable my custom scrollbar from appearing horizontally?

Tags: css

I've set up my own custom scrollbar with CSS, and I'd like to know know how to **only** apply these settings to my vertical crossbar.

I've looked up other posts to fix this, but haven't been successful in implementing their solutions in my project.

Any fix that either removes my horizontal scrollbar completely or resets its settings to default would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgb(26, 23, 23);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: hsl(270, 2.9%, 48.7%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: hsl(270, 2.9%, 78.7%);
}
```

edit: The problem seems to have been related to other pre-built styles overriding overflow-x. `overflow-x: hidden !important;` solved the issue.

Comment: Why not try `body {
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}`?

Comment: @bimjhi Thank you for replying. While `overflow-y: hidden` does hide my vertical scrollbar, `overflow-x: hidden` doesn't hide the horizontal one. The horizontal scrollbar is the one I'm trying to remove or reset back to default, as it's overlapping other elements.

Comment: Then try to wrap your content into <div>. Set `position:relative; overflow-x: hidden;` for this div. Finally, try `position:fixed; overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: @bimjhi The scroll bar is only visible on desktop. All scrollbar properties are changed to unset for mobile.

Comment: Please let me know whether you want me to post an answer regarding `overflow-x: hidden !important;`

Comment: @bimjhi I'm relatively new to posting on Stack Overflow. If it's common practice to do so, then please. Otherwise, I don't think it'll be necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questioner have faced a problem that a WebKit engine won't allow him to remove customized horizontal scrollbar.

It seems that the implementation of such a removal vary from one browser to another and there's no universal way to hide scrollbars.

> ```
> Using overflow: hidden will disable the scroll and that’s not what we want.
> ```
>
> So we’ll need another way to hide the scrollbar.
> Unfortunately, there is no universal CSS property that does something
> like this
>
> ```
> div {
>   scrollbar-visibility: hidden; /* <--- I wish we had this one !! */
> }
> We’ll need to implement different CSS properties for each browser.
> ```
>
> For Firefox, we can set the scroll-bar width to none.
>
> ```
> scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
> For IE, we’ll need to use -ms prefix property to define scrollbar style
>
> -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
> For Chrome and Safari. We’ll have to use CSS scrollbar selector.
> ```
>
> Then apply display: none to hide it.
>
> ```
> ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
>     display: none; /* Chrome Safari */
> }
> Or you can set it’s width and height to 0.
>
> ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
>   width: 0;
>   height: 0;
> }
> ```

https://redstapler.co/css-hidden-scrollbar-while-scrollable-element/

Nevertheless, the following solution took effect in questioner's situation:

```
overflow-x: hidden !important;
```